# Find Annotation on map with location

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

When I add an annotation on my map, I want to highlighted it.
I know I must use
`mapView1.selectAnnotation(annotation: MKAnnotation!, animated: Bool)`

But I can't get my MKAnnotation object, all I have is the location (CLLocationCoordinate2D) of the annotation.

My question is How I can get the specific Annotation knowing his location ?

**EDIT :** Solution found in theory but had a bug :

`for annotation in self.mapView1.annotations as! [MKAnnotation] {
        println("  ")
        let annotLatitude = annotation.coordinate.latitude
        let annotLongitude = annotation.coordinate.longitude
        let eventLatitude = self.appDel!.lastEventCoords.latitude
        let eventLongitude = self.appDel!.lastEventCoords.longitude
        println("annotLatitude : (annotLatitude) , annotLongitude : (annotLongitude)")
        println("eventLatitude : (eventLatitude) , eventLongitude : (eventLongitude)")

       if (annotLatitude == eventLatitude && annotLongitude == eventLongitude) {
                  self.lastAnnotationAdded = annotation
                  println("Location equals")
                  self.mapView1.selectAnnotation(self.lastAnnotationAdded!, animated: true)
                  break
        }`

Output :

`annotLatitude : 47.4799380142289 , annotLongitude : -0.44762351737708
eventLatitude : 47.4799380142289 , eventLongitude : -0.44762351737708`

The latitude and longitude are exactly the same but the "if" loop is not executed ! Sometimes it works but sometimes not. HOW is it possible ???

**EDIT2 : Problem solved**
To compare the coordinates, I had to truncate them before with the func tronc()

Comment: Because `==` does not mean what you think it does. These are Double values; you cannot reliably compare them using `==`.

Comment: For anyone searching: `trunc(annotLatitude)` is what he's talking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MKMapView has a list of its annotations, its `annotations` property. So look through those until you find the one you want (the one with the right `coordinate`).

Comment: weird bug added, sometimes the loop is not executed despite the values compared are exactly equals